# MDL- componentHandler.upgradeDom(); after ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, material-design

I have following ajax setup using Google material design lite:

**first.php**

```
<button class="rhm_add_button" type="button" >
    Show                      
</button>
<div class="rhm_add"></div>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.rhm_add_button').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", 
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: ({ action: 'rhmp_indi_form'}),
                    success: function(data){
                            jQuery('.rhm_add').html(data);
                },                  
                error: function(data)  
                {  
                alert("Error!");
                return false;
                }  
                }); 
         }); 
     }); 
</script>
```

**Functions.php**

```
function rhmp_indi_form_callback() {  
    $template_part_path = 'page-parts/second_page';
    get_template_part($template_part_path);
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_rhmp_indi_form', 'rhmp_indi_form_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rhmp_indi_form', 'rhmp_indi_form_callback');
```

**Second_file.php**

```
 <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">                                       
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="title">Name</label>                                        
 </div>
```

As you can see I am using the MDL and when the contents are loaded via ajax, they do not work properly and I found the following solution from the github: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1043

The solution was that I need to use "componentHandler.upgradeDom();" after the ajax call and I am not sure how to do it.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` after you have done inserting any dynamic elements into the DOM.

In your case, call it after `jQuery('.rhm_add').html(data)`

Comment: this doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 2):

```
       success: function(data){
                        jQuery('.rhm_add').html(data);
                     window.componentHandler.upgradeDom();                      },
```

Comment: Add some description to the answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.